Значение слова «утрировать»
Я ищу все значения слова «утрировать».

А почему метка "старославянский"?

Скорее всего, автор хотел прояснить этимологию слова, а значение можно в словаре посмотреть.

Про этимологию у автора не было ни слова. Её ведь тоже можно посмотреть в словаре.

Слова раскрываются в контексте. В Нацкорпусе нужно искать все значения.

Суть вопроса действительно НЕПОНЯТНА. О каких значениях идет речь? Зачем была указана метка "старославянский"? Я думаю, что надо строже подходить к формулировкам вопроса: ЗАКРЫВАТЬ их  и отправлять  на доработку.   Ну и менять метки без согласия автора тоже не лучший выход, что видно по ответам.

Предлагаю вам два ресурса, на которых можно посмотреть все значения  практически любого слова.
Словари и энциклопедии на Академике
Словари на сайте "Грамота"
Набираете слово "утрировать" в поиске и получаете его значения в толковых словарях:
[от франц. outrer]. (кого-что). Слишком подчеркнуть — подчёркивать, исказить — искажать преувеличением, подчёркиванием каких-либо сторон, особенностей. Утрировать стиль писателя. Утрировать кого-либо. Утрировать чью-либо задумчивость. Утрировать чью-либо походку, манеру поведения. // Слишком исказить — искажать что-либо; довести — доводить до абсурда. Утрировать чьи-либо мысли. Утрировать ситуацию, положение (БТС);
представить (-влять) в преувеличенном виде, исказить (-ажать) односторонним подчёркиванием чего-нибудь. Утрировать чьи-нибудь слова. Актёр утрирует в игре (ТС Ожегова).
Дополнение (для новой метки)
Этимология (из словаря Н. М. Шанского):

Утри́ровать. Заимств. во второй половине XIX в. из франц. яз., где outrer «утрировать» < «преувеличивать» — производное от outre < ст.-фр. ultre, восходящего к лат. ultra «более, далее, сверх». См. ультрамарин. Ср. преувеличивать (с исходным великий).

Самые ранние примеры из Нацкорпуса (слово используется приблизительно 200 лет)
Секретарь (г. Пономарев) слишком утрировал свою ролю в противность автору и здравому смыслу, вырывая бумагу у повытчика... (С. Т. Аксаков. 1-е письмо из Петербурга. К издателю “Московского Вестника” (1828)).
Прежде они подражали старине греческой, которую утрировали, коверкали бесчеловечно; теперь она им надоела, и я подсунул им другую пошлую старину, именно великобританскую, на которую они бросились, как бешеные, и которую опять стали утрировать и коверкать (О. И. Сенковский. Большой выход у Сатаны (1832)).

Три - это совершенство, совершенное число, фигура(треугольник), гармония, у+три+ровать - уходить от три, то есть уходить от совершенного представления, понимания. Обычно имеется ввиду преувеличивать, то есть наделять лишними, излишними качествами, свойствами и тп. что-то. Недостаток можно восполнить, а лишнее, лишку, лихо порой бывает сложнее сдержать и привести в норму. Лихо > недостаток в понимании негативного воздействия.
Лихо одноглазое - это персонаж из русской народной сказки, похожей чем-то на историю про циклопа из приключений Одиссея, но с несколько иными, более фундаментальными смыслами.

Есть слово утраивать (несовер. к утроить), которое точно от собир. трое, например: Премию удваивали и утраивали. Но не утрировали. И треугольник не совершенен, скорее прочен.

@shampar Треугольник совершенная фигура, самая основная у пифагорейцев была, не квадрат, а именно треугольник и число три. Утрировать и утраивать -несколько разные основы, возможно поэтому. Кроме траи-трои - уже не совсем три, изменённое три - тройка.  У приставки "У-" есть ряд значений, основная это "уход от", первое, но есть и третье "3. Обозначает: распространение действия на весь объект." - поэтому утроить - это третье значение, помножить на три, либо шестое - "
6. Обозначает: прочность, основательность действия. Угнездиться, усесться, увлечься.".

Но с утрировать нет сомнений потому что там 1 значение "У-" - уход от указанного.

А пифагорейцы грубо говоря занимались тем, что пытались весь мир триангулировать) триангуляция это такой процесс разбития сложных поверхностей на треугольники, ну и это работает для поверхностей 3 и вроде 4 степени измерений, а для пятой не всегда) Короче из математики заморочки. Ну и Троица туда же. Не то, что я хочу мистики навести, но мышление в тех, кто язык придумывал было мистическое, так что без знания определённых моментов важных для человека того времени никуда. Люди прошлого имели иное представление о мире и отражали это в языке.

Вопрос-то не об изначальном значении на языках людей прошлого. Вообще не об этимологии. Вопрос даже не сформулирован: автор, похоже, уснул или вспомнил о других заданиях, не таких скучных.

Этимологию тоже можно посмотреть в словаре...
Утрировать от ultra? А ДАЛЬШЕ ЧТО? И где, кстати, старославянский корень (если по первоначальной метке вопроса)?
Из словаря
ultra-словообразовательный элемент, означающий "за пределами" (ультрафиолетовый) или "чрезвычайно" (ультрасовременный), от латинского ultra- от ultra (прил. и преп.) "за пределами, с другой стороны, дальше, мимо, сверх, поперек", от PIE ol-tero-, суффиксной формы корня *al- "за пределами".
В обиходе с начала 19 века, она, по-видимому, произошла от французских политических обозначений. Как собственное слово, существительное, означающее "экстремист" различных мастей, оно впервые зарегистрировано в 1817 году, от французского ultra, сокращение от ultra-royaliste "крайний роялист".
Записи, ссылающиеся на ultra-
ultra vires
Латынь, буквально "за пределами возможностей", от ultra "за пределами" (см. ultra-) + vires "сила, напористость, энергичность", множественное число от vis (см. vim). Обычно "вне законных или конституционных полномочий суда и т.д."
Здесь явно нужен комментарий специалиста)
По какой модели образовался глагол – от ultra с усечением Л из фонетических соображений? Или учитывалось еще что-то?  Также интересно: в старославянском языке были слова с формантом ultra?
